# Applications on Newtons' laws

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, acceleration, applied-physics

A light string passes over a smooth pulley and carries at one of its ends a body of mass 90 grams and it carries a body of mass 50 grams at its other end.the system started its motion from rest when the mass 90 gram was at height 140 cm away from the ground 
Find: the time elapsed afterwards until the string becomes in tension again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: What had you tried?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).